# Extract certain rows in Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

The code below was designed to analyze the dataset read from a CSV file and make some simple conclusions about the dataset.

I didn't understand why the part of codes below to print cant work:

(

```
print(f'Year with the highest total number of Home nursing: { **data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]['year']}')
```

)

Erro throw:

```
     File "<ipython-input-97-8633de9c62f8>", line 37
        print(f'Year with the highest total number of Home nursing: { data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]['year']}')
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[dataset from csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4taGL.png)

But it works when I change the code to two separate parts:
([Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oelaf.png)

```
print('Year with the highest Home Nursing count: ' )
print(data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]['year'])
```

)

```
import numpy as np

### Read the csv file using genfromtxt
filename = "number-of-home-care-visits.csv"
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=['i2', 'U50', 'i8'], 
                     delimiter=',', names=True)

#print(data)
#print(data.shape)

### Print out total rows of data in the file
print(f'There are altogether {len(data)} rows in the data file {filename}')
print()

### Print out the number of years of data captured
data_years = data['year']
years = np.unique(data_years)
print(f'There are {len(years)} years of data captured from {years.min()} to {years.max()}')
print()

## Extract only the rows with Home Nirsing Type" - using boolean indexing
keyword1 = 'Home Nursing'
data_homeN = data[data['type'] == keyword1]
#print(data_homeN)

print()

keyword2 = 'Home Medical'
data_homeM = data[data['type'] == keyword2]
print(data_homeM)


### Print out the years which has the highest Home Nursing count
max_Nursing = data_homeN['count'].max()
argmax_Nursing = data_homeN['count'].argmax()

#print(f'Year with the highest total number of Home nursing: { data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]['year']}')
print('Year with the highest Home Nursing count: ' )
print(data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]['year'])
print(f'\nCount: \n{ max_Nursing } ')
print()
```

Comment: Did you try ```print(f'Year with the highest total number of Home nursing: { data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]["year"]}')```

Comment: yes, this one works, could u pls point out my problem

Comment: what is the difference between "" and ''  exactly

Comment: the  instruction from this question uses '',which has disturbed me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser gets confused by

```
print(f'Year with the highest total number of Home nursing: { **data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]['year']}')
```

because the first `'` opens a string, and the next one (the one opening `'year'`) closes it, making the string inside the `print` not contigious.

---

In Python, `'` and `"` are the same, but they don't interrupt each other when nesting strings, thus

```
print(f'Year with the highest total number of Home nursing: { **data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]["year"]}')
```

or

```
print(f"Year with the highest total number of Home nursing: { **data_homeN[argmax_Nursing]['year']}")
```

will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know this phenomenon but failed  to recognize it